# Passing one parameter reffering to another - accessing REST method from Android

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit

In my Android app I connect through REST to Delphi application on Firebird server using Retrofit. 
There is REST method "`SelectSQL`" which takes two parameters: `String` and `TJSONObject`.
For example:

```
select name from employee where employee_id=:id

{"id":10001}
```

This is part of interface where I declare methods: I used string and JSONObject.

```
 @POST("datasnap/rest/TstBaseMethods/SelectSQL/{param,param2}")
Call<Logowanie> selectSQL(@Header("Authorization") String credentials, @Query("param") String param, @Query("param2") JSONObject param2 );
```

In my MainActivity.java I use:

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    StreamREST gerritAPI = retrofit.create(StreamREST.class);

    String dane = Credentials.basic("admin","admin");
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("NAGL",11101);
        String dd = obj.toString();
        Call<Logowanie> sql = gerritAPI.selectSQL(dane,"select n.datadok from nagl n where n.id_nagl=:NAGL",obj);
        sql.enqueue(new Callback<Logowanie>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Logowanie> call, Response<Logowanie> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Logowanie log = response.body();
                    String result = log.result[0];
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,generujWynik(log));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Logowanie> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t.getMessage() );
            }
        });
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is Retrofit doesn't properly encodes second parameter. When I launch app, I get message about bad second parameter and URL looks like that:

http://192.168.94.155:9000/datasnap/rest/TstBaseMethods/SelectSQL/%7Bparam,param2%7D?param=select%20n.datadok%20from%20nagl%20n%20where%20n.id_nagl%3D:NAGL&param2={%22NAGL%22:11101}

You can see: "param2={%22NAGL%22:11101}" where param2 looks like:

```
{"NAGL":11101}
```

Brackets  and "" aren't encoded. Where is my mistake? I admit these are my first steps with Android and REST with Stackoverflow as well, but I've already made basics: I launched basic REST method and it worked. Now is problem for me.

If I didn't include important parts of my code, just tell me and I will do it.

I can add that it's about DataSnap REST from Embarcadero.

Comment: Have you tried url encoding the params2 string?  `String query = URLEncoder.encode(dd, "utf-8");`

Comment: As an advice, don't make a webAPI taking SQL request. You will be open for SQL Injection, and will pose a big security risk.

Comment: @AdilSoomro can you clarify? I'm not using dd variable, i just use this for debugging. 
Do you suggest changing:
Call<Logowanie> sql = gerritAPI.selectSQL(dane,"select n.datadok from nagl n where n.id_nagl=:NAGL",obj);
to:
Call<Logowanie> sql = gerritAPI.selectSQL(dane,"select n.datadok from nagl n where n.id_nagl=:NAGL",query);?

Comment: @JFPicard, thanks, surely I will take care of it later, but for now I just want to properly pass this parameter.

Comment: When I try to use method with variable query, I get messy, invalid String
%257B%2522NAGL%2522%253A11101%257D

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It turned out that I had to use @Body Retrofit annotation as this parameter should go in body of the request.